# The api not work in Postman when requested by url

Tags: php, laravel, postman, laravel-passport

i have start the server using xampp

http://localhost/api/login

used this url in postman for request and still get this error

> **Not Found
> The requested URL was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.54 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1p PHP/8.2.0 Server at localhost Port 80**

my route in api.php is

`Route::post('login',[userController::class,'userLogin']);`

I have tried with `php artisan serve` with url
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login
but didn't work

Comment: Have you tried `http://localhost/login`

Comment: does it work in a browser/with `curl` ??

Comment: yeah i have tried http://localhost/login but didn't work

Comment: are you sure that you are listening on all network interfaces? have you checked with e.g. `netstat`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear your route cache by

```
php artisan route:cache
```

This is common when testing with Postman. Once your routes cache is cleared, your route will be picked up by Postman.